# How to parse xml and simultaneously save to sqlite asynchronously in iOS 7?

Tags: sqlite, asynchronous, xml-parsing, ios7, nsnotifications

I am parsing XML Document by using `TBXML` but I have to Parse XML and store data to SQLite asynchronously with notifications [that is Parsing and storing data in SQLite]. Please help me to overcome this problems. Thanks in advance....

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @Virussmca I clearly mention that, I parsed and storing data to my Database but XML String contains Images links that too I have to store in my database. I dont want to block my main thread. Please help me its urgent....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that You can use `NSNotificationCenter` and `GCD`,

First set NSNotificationCenter for your process using,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(dataStore) 
                                                 name:@"dataStoreComplete" object:nil];


- (void)dataStore
{
    NSLog(@"Received Notification - Data stored in databse");
}
```

You GCD for parsing and storing in database

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // switch to a background thread and perform your expensive operation
 //  parse and store all data in sqlite,


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // switch back to the main thread to update your UI
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dataStoreComplete" object:nil]; 
    });
});
```

Comment: I'll first add the your and see the result then I'll accept your answer...